# I have two debit cards for same account with different limits can I use two cards for maximum withdrawal?

Tags: india, banking, debit-card, withdrawal, atm

I got State Bank of India Classic debit card with a daily ATM transaction limit of 20,000 INR per Day, and also got State Bank of India International Visa card with Daily ATM limit of Transaction 40,000 INR per Day. I have got two debit cards for the same account.

My question is can I use Both cards for a day to make ATM Cash Withdrawal sum of 60,000[Classic: 20,000+Visa: 40,000] INR per Day?

-Thank You

Comment: Ask State Bank of India

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 debit cards, it's likely that either the first one has expired or you have requested an upgrade,  you have a new debit card. The limit on the new card will apply.

Comment: This was my exact thought upon reading the question. Until proven otherwise, I would assume this is correct.

Comment: Actually, SBI allows account holders to have/use 2 or up to 6 different types of debit cards[ex: Mastro, VISA, RuPay, Gold, Platinum...]. every card charged for annual maintenance. as I mentioned in my question my 2 debit cards are different and both are working fine. I am currently making transactions using my 2 cards. so your answer seems not accurate.